# How can I make a set of images correspond to an array in a GUI?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am trying to make a character generator in java swing. You click the generate button, and it randomly pulls two character names from an array and displays them as JLabels (newGenerate, newGenerate2) in the GUI (one name on top, and the other on the bottom). I would like for an image of the randomly chosen character to appear when their name is pulled. I have no clue how to do it. Forgive me if this doesn't make any sense, I am new to this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Main implements ActionListener{
  JFrame f = new JFrame("ℂ ");
  Random r = new Random();
  JButton generate = new JButton("Generate");
  JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
  JLabel newGenerate = new JLabel("Character", JLabel.CENTER);
  JLabel newGenerate2 = new JLabel("Character", JLabel.CENTER);
  Color custBlue = new Color(10, 63, 250);
  Color custOrange = new Color(251,167,88);
  Color saturatedCustOrange = new Color(254, 127, 46);
  ImageIcon back_image = new ImageIcon("images/back_ground.jpg");
  JLabel img2 = new JLabel(back_image);
  ImageIcon wheel = new ImageIcon("images/loading_wheel.gif");
  JLabel img = new JLabel(wheel);

  String[] names1 = {"<html><p align='center'>Character1</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character2</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character3</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character4</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character6</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character6</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character7</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character8</p></html>", "<html><p align='center'>Character9</p></html>",};
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main o = new Main();
    o.gui();
  }
  public void gui(){
    f.setSize(500, 400);
    
    this.newGenerate.setBounds(250,190, 100, 40);
    this.newGenerate.setForeground(saturatedCustOrange);
    f.add(this.newGenerate);

    this.newGenerate2.setBounds(250,10, 100, 40);
    this.newGenerate2.setForeground(saturatedCustOrange);
    f.add(this.newGenerate2);

    this.generate.setBounds(28, 140, 120, 40);
    generate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    this.generate.setForeground(custOrange);
    this.generate.setBackground(custBlue);
    this.generate.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(this.generate);

    this.clear.setBounds(28, 190, 120, 40);
    clear.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    this.clear.setForeground(custOrange);
    this.clear.setBackground(custBlue);
    this.clear.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(this.clear);

    
    img.setBounds(0, -10,500,400);
    f.add(img);

    img2.setBounds(0, -10,500,400);
    f.add(img2);
       
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.getSource() == this.clear){
    img.setVisible(true);
    this.newGenerate.setText("Character");
    this.newGenerate2.setText("Character");
  }
  else{
    this.newGenerate.setText(this.returnChar());
    this.newGenerate2.setText(this.returnChar());
    img.setVisible(false); 
  }
}

  public String returnChar() {
    int ranNum = r.nextInt(this.names1.length);
    
    return this.names1[ranNum];
 }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it could be an XY problem, so I'll ask for some clarification. Are you specifically wanting your images to be loaded into an array, or are you wanting to get an image from an already-loaded array of images and then display one of them? http://xyproblem.info

Comment: I suppose I need to add them to an array first. I just have all of my images loaded up into a folder right now. After they are loaded into an array, I will need to display them. To clarify, I need an image to appear for both of the JLables being displayed in my GUI.

Comment: Create a `CharacterName` class to hold a `String` name and a `BufferedImage` image.  Create an array of `CharacterName` objects.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: You're going to probably run into problems having a [null layout](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)